# Bon jovi documentary

Tags: music-video

Hi I'm looking for a great Bon jovi / Rock and roll documentary I saw in England in the noughties.
I vaguely remember it focusing on Bon jovi but it had other bands talked about. I specifically remember one groupie that said that she was forced to sign a contract as to not reveal secrets etc of her hanging out with the band.
Any help would be much appreciated thank you